# Javascript object initialization and evaluation order

Tags: javascript, semantics

If I write

```
var a = [1,2];
var b = {
  foo: a.pop(),
  bar: a.pop()
};
```

What is the value of `b`, according to the specification?

(By experiment, it's `{foo: 2, bar: 1}`, but I worry whether this is implementation-specific.)

Comment: Why would it be implementation-specific? `pop` mutates the original array.

Comment: @elclanrs, I think what the question is getting at is whether the values of the properties of object `b` will always be evaluated in the order in which they are listed in the code.

Comment: Oh, I see... Now that's actually a good question, but while the order of properties in an object is trivial, the order of evaluation is not, so I'd say this is non-issue but I may be wrong...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [ECMAScript section 11.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) defining how the `ObjectLiteral` production is parsed.

In particular:

> `PropertyNameAndValueList` , `PropertyName` : `AssignmentExpression`
>   is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate PropertyNameAndValueList.
> 2. Evaluate PropertyName.
> 3. Evaluate AssignmentExpression.
>
> ...

Where (1) is a recursive definition.

This means the leftmost item in an object literal will get evaluated first, and so `{foo: 2, bar: 1}` is indeed spec-mandated.

Answer (score 1):

They are evaluated in the order they are written.