# Object properties referencing other object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I do:

```
outerobject={
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: this.a + this.b,
};

console.log(outerobject.a);
console.log(outerobject.b);
console.log(outerobject.c);
```

I expect:

```
1
2
3
```

I get:

```
1
2
NaN
```

Why do I get a NaN?

Comment: Because `this` isn't `outerobject`. Add `"use strict";` at the top of your code and you'll get a nice error message instead of a silent failure: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined`.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403029/order-of-attribute-evaluation-in-javascript-object-literals).

Comment: @Blender: There won't be an error in strict mode if the code is running globally, or in a function that has its `this` set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the object `this` is assigned a reference to the `window` or the global object.  You need to use a function which will have `this` refer to a reference of the object.

```
var outerobject={ a: 1, b: 2, c: function(){return this.a + this.b}};
var outerobject2={ a: 1, b: 2, c: console.log(this)}; //logs window/global object

console.log(outerobject.c());//outputs 3
```

or use a function constructor:

```
function MyObject(){
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
    this.c = this.a + this.b;
    console.log(this);
}

var myObject = new MyObject();
```

The key is the `function` determines the scope of `this`.  When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aRFLn/

[Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: The explanation is correct, but I wouldn't use the suggested solutions. Using a method requires a different syntax to be called (btw, should be called `getC()`) and property created inside a constructor won't update it's value as someone may expect.

Comment: @Pavlo Good point about the function constructor, I guess that wouldn't work so well if the object changes

Comment: All depends on if OP intends for it just in initialization or in every access of that property. Not much context was given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to get the sum of property values `a` and `b`. You'll need a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) for this:

```
var outerobject = {
    a: 1, // inside a property value `this` is `window`
    b: 2,
    get c() {
        return this.a + this.b; // inside a getter function 'this' is `outerobject`
    }
};
```

Then you can use `outerobject.c`. It will also be re-evaluated each time you call it:

```
outerobject.c; // 3
outerobject.a++;
outeobject.c; // 4
```

Comment: @palvo Is that syntax correct?  I thought properties of an object took the associative hash form of `key:value`

Comment: @KevinBowersox: His syntax is correct (ECMAScript 5). Of course you could just copy the code into your console to test it.

Comment: @BlueSkies unless he is using IE 8 :)

Comment: Yes, well that would make him a masochist, wouldn't it. :-D

Comment: @BlueSkies Just did.  Thanks! Is there a name for this construct?

Comment: Yes, it's called a getter. (Don't recall if that's spec terminology though.) See the link in the answer. There's a setter syntax too.

Comment: @BlueSkies Thanks, learned something new answering a question.

Answer (score 0):

In your case 'this' could be any number of things depending on where this is being called. In your case it most likely is the `window` object. Since `window` probably doesn't have `a` and `b` defined so you get `NaN`.

Here's a good example on how this works: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html